# How to prevent pdf script code from executing?

Tags: 14.04, scripts, pdf, malware

Is there a setting inside **Ubuntu Default PDF viewer** (***evince***) or **Okular** to disable *embedded script execution* in PDF files ?

It is a really important setting, that adds an extra security measure against PDF-Malware (e.g [Pidief](http://www.sans.org/security-resources/malwarefaq/pidief.php)), thus in my opinion a must-have of every modern PDF-viewer.

If these PDF viewers do not have such a *setting*, are there any similar *applications* that include an *option* for *script-blocking* ?

I am aware of **Foxit Reader** that does the job but it is a *windows program* and works only using **Wine**.

Comment: I agree that there should be such an option. However, the Pidief example is not a very good choice, as it is set to attack Windows systems (something you don't have, using Ubuntu). In order to really be sure, and if it is worth the bother to you, you might look at the products by Appligent; if I remember correctly, they have an utility which strips all active elements and features. I don't know if it is ported to Ubuntu; you'd have to ask.

Comment: So far I have found some software [Dider_Steven's_PDF_Tools](http://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/pdf-tools/) written in python that help you detect malware in PDF, but they do not offer the ability to block script code while reading a PDF file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evince doesn't support javascripts so not an issue.

Okular according to [Okular News dated July 29, 2008](https://okular.kde.org/news.php): Preliminary (really basic and most probably incomplete) support for JavaScript in PDF documents. No update has been made since on this subject so I believe there is no security threat here.